# Docker Alpine build fails on mysqlclient installation with error: Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux, mysql-connector-python

I'm encountering a problem when building a Docker image using a Python-based Dockerfile. I'm trying to use the mysqlclient library (version 2.2.0) and Django (version 4.2.2). Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev mariadb-connector-c-dev && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

The problem arises when the Docker build process reaches the point of installing the mysqlclient package. I get the following error: *Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name*
To address this issue, I tried adding pkgconfig to the apk add command, Unfortunately, this didn't help and the same error persists.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if ti didn't worked, which was the Exception when executing adding pkg-config ?

Comment: @tremendows same error: Exception: can not find valid pkg-config name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue and here's how I did it:
Here is the new Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-deps gcc musl-dev libffi-dev2 pkgconf mariadb-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache mariadb-connector-c-dev && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
    apk del build-deps
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
mysqlclient==2.2.0
Django~=4.2.0
```

I hope this will help someone who visits this post in the future.

Answer (score 28):

I'm using `python:3.11.3-slim-bullseye` instead of `python:3.11-alpine` image, but I had the same problem.
So you have 2 options:

1. Downgrade the `mysqlclient` to a previous version, ex: `mysqlclient==2.1.1`.
2. And now, since the `pkg-config` is needed for `mysqlclient==2.2.0` and on. Add pkg-config to the container. Would be something like this...

```
FROM python:3.11.3-slim-bullseye

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y gcc default-libmysqlclient-dev pkg-config \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install mysqlclient \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

TIP: Maybe you're lacking the instalation of the `default-libmysqlclient-dev` or `libmysqlclient` in the container.

Hope it helps. :D

Answer (score 8):

mysqlclient 2.2.0 added a dependency on pkg-config, which might not exist as such on alpine (update: it appears to, now). See https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/620

You might have luck pinning to a prior version of mysqlclient

Answer (score 8):

**Install build dependencies ( specially - pkg-config )**

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential pkg-config
```

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue inside of a slim Docker image (python3.10-slim).

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install pkg-config
```

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

if u are using Mac, u can use this commands

```
brew install pkg-config && pip3 install mysqlclient==2.2.2
```

that will work without issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating before adding pkgconfig ? I've tried and it works perfectly.

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN apk update
RUN apk add pkgconfig
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev mariadb-connector-c-dev 
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: not working in my system thanks for trying

Comment: which is the output error?

Comment: Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
thanks for help

Comment: Same. Not working on the latest Alpine. Same error as @IdanB

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm using a local WSL2 environment so this solution might not be applicable to your situation.

I followed the build instructions at [mysqlclient  PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) so you may consider adding those build instructions to your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Alpine 3.18.3, Django >= 4.2.0, and mysqlclient >= 2.2.0.  To get this combination working the following Dockerfile built successfully and app started in the container:

```
FROM python:alpine
apk update && apk upgrade; \
apk add pkgconfig; \
apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev mariadb-dev mariadb-connector-c-dev; \
```

Comment: `apk add pkgconfig` and `apk add --no-cache gcc ...` could be combined in 1 call: `apk add --no-cache pkgconfig gcc musl-dev mariadb-dev mariadb-connector-c-dev;`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on `python:3.9-slim`. Here's what worked for me:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim 
RUN apt update && apt install -y pkg-config gcc \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev pkg-config
RUN pip install mysqlclient==2.2.1
```